# Error with dates in stored procedure calling Oracle database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which calls an Oracle database and returns a result set.

The stored procedure is

```
DECLARE
    @IntStartDate Varchar(50),
    @IntEndDate Varchar(50),
    @ConStartDate Varchar(50),
    @ConEndDate Varchar(50),
    @Query Varchar(Max)

--Convert SQL to UNIX Time
SET @IntStartDate = CONVERT(varchar(50), @StartDate, 23)
SET @IntEndDate = CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate), 23)

SET @ConStartDate = (DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', @IntStartDate))
SET @ConEndDate = (DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', @IntEndDate ))

SET @Query = 'select * 
              from openquery([linkedserver],
''
SELECT 
sm.movement_type as "Movement Type",
sm.reference as "RMA Number",
cri.reason_code as "RMA Reason",
cri.sales_document_num as "Order Number",
sh.customer_account as "Customer Account",
sm.product_code as "SKU",
cri.long_description_1 as "Product Name",
to_char(trunc(date ''1970-01-01'' + sm.movement_date * interval ''1'' second),''DD/MM/YYYY'') as "Movement Date",
sm.quantity as "Quantity",
sm.change_user as "User",
sm.warehouse_code as "Warehouse",
sm.receipt_location as "Location"
FROM
STOCK_MOVEMENT SM
left join CUSTOMER_RETURN_ITEM CRI on sm.reference = cri.rma_num
left join sales_header sh on cri.sales_document_num = sh.sales_document_num
WHERE sm.reference like ''5%''
AND sm.change_user not in (''l.hill'', ''d.newell'', ''p.willman'', ''s.parkinson'')
AND sm.movement_type = ''RMASTK''
AND sm.movement_date  BETWEEN ' + cast(@ConStartDate as varchar)+ ' and ' + cast(@conEndDate as varchar) + '

'')
'
```

However I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
> Incorrect syntax near '1970'.

The date part seems to work in another stored procedure and I have compared them.. but for the life of me I can't see the difference.

Any help appreciated.

C

Comment: Please, try to create **minimal** reproducible example and you'll locate the step which fails the execution. Start with `select date '1970-01-01'`, then add other expressions and you'll find the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The error was to do with the number of quoates it needs to be four rather than two otherwise it escapes the field.